# $|f(z)| \le c|z||Log(z)|$ implies that $f$ is identically $)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Suppose that $f$ is an analytic function  in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and that $|f(z)| \le c|z||\log(z)|$, for some constant $c>0$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z$. ($\log(z)$ is the principal logarithm of $z$.)

My attempt:

I know that $f$ has a removable singularity at the origin, since $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)=0$$

Therefore 
$$f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+...$$

and 
$$\frac{f(z)}{z}=a_1+a_2z+...$$

But  $|\log(z)|$ grows at a slower rate than any polynomial, so $a_n=0$, $\forall n\ge2$, and $f(z)=a_1z$.

After this i got stuck. Any hints?

Comment: Put it back in the inequality and evaluate at $z=1$.

Comment: Thanks @conditionalMethod it's way simples than I thought

Comment: I don 't think your argument to show that $f(z)=a_1z$ is valid.

Comment: @KaboMurphy it's definitely not

Comment: @CélioAugusto $\frac{f(z)}{z(z-1)}$ is entire and bounded

Comment: @mathworker21 Your proof is much better than the one I was thinking of. Please post it as an answer.